# ¿WPF, Borre SelectionChanged en public partial class MainWindow y luego en el Xalm, me da un error cs 1061 y persiste?

Tags: c#, xaml

Como no lo necesitaba, borre seletionChanged del comboBox en el codigo y luego en Xalm, pero persiste el error asi que puse todo en su lugar devuelta tampoco funciona (cabe aclarar que el programa corre en la sumilación y funciona),pero el error persiste el error es el siguente;

cs 1061 'MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'CbxDestino_SelectionChanged' and no accessible extension method 'CbxDestino_SelectionChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Se que parece algo raro para preguntar pero nunca me había dado un eror así y no solucionarlo rápido
prove poniendo X:Name porque estaba Name solo al Xalm pero lo mismo no funciona .Desde gracias por responder

Answer (score 1):

Asegúrate de haber borrado la referencia al evento en el XAML:

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="207,166,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
```

- Remover **SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"**

Si aún no te funciona, prueba Limpiando la solución (Clic derecho sobre el proyecto en el explorador de soluciones, opción Limpiar) y finalmente recompila la solución.